# Rails: next/prev metatags for index page with JS pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

For SEO reasons I want to give Google more info about our magazine, which is part of our website. Google recognizes that there is paginated content. So I was told to add, for every page of the magazine, `next` and `prev` metatags/links like so (for example for page 3):

```
<link rel="prev" href="http://www.bla.com/de/magazin?page=2" />
<link rel="next" href="http://www.bla.com/de/magazin?page=4" />
```

We're using JSON with the Kaminari gem to paginate our articles. 
Here's the `magazine_controller`'s index action:

```
def index
  @articles = MagazineArticle.visible
                             .includes(:magazine_category)
                             .order(published_at: :desc)
                             .page(params[:page]).per(7)
  @slider_articles = @articles.first(3)
  @advertisement = Advertisement.for_start_page

  #set_pagination_meta_tags(params[:page])
  set_magazine_meta_tags

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render_new_page(@articles, @advertisement) }
  end
end

# the method that renders the new page (as JSON)
def render_new_page(articles, advertisement)
  render json: {
    content: {
      articles: render_to_string(
        partial: 'magazine/article_page',
        locals: { articles: articles, advertisement: advertisement }
      ),
      link: render_to_string(
        partial: 'magazine/load_more_button',
        locals: { articles: articles }
      )
    }
  }
end
```

Also we are using the [Metatags gem](https://github.com/kpumuk/meta-tags) to handle metatags.

I wrote a method which adds the links relative to 
the current page with a method which I call in the index action
as you can see in above controller code:

```
def set_pagination_meta_tags(page)
  page = page.to_i
  case page
  when 0..1
    set_meta_tags(next: magazine_url(I18n.locale, page: 2))
  when @articles.total_pages
    set_meta_tags(prev: magazine_url(I18n.locale, page: @articles.total_pages - 1))
  when 2..@articles.total_pages - 1
    set_meta_tags(prev: magazine_url(I18n.locale, page: page-1))
    set_meta_tags(next: magazine_url(I18n.locale, page: page+1))
  end
end
```

But this works only for the first page, then JSON is used to navigate / load more and this doesn't change the meta tags.

Before going deeper i want to know: Is it possible at all to set these links up? Does it make sense for this kind of (dynamic) pagination? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to what you are already using you could just return the some rendered meta_pagination partial which contains

```
= rel_next_prev_link_tags @articles
```

Your `render_new_page` would look like this

```
def render_new_page(articles, advertisement)
  render json: {
    content: {
      articles: render_to_string(
        partial: 'magazine/article_page',
        locals: { articles: articles, advertisement: advertisement }
      ),
      link: render_to_string(
        partial: 'magazine/load_more_button',
        locals: { articles: articles }
      ),
      meta_pagination: render_to_string(
        partial: 'layouts/meta_pagination',
        locals: { articles: articles }
      )
    }
  }
end
```

(adjust the path to the meta pagination partial)

Then in your javascript remove the rel next/prev

```
$("head link[rel='next']").remove();
$("head link[rel='prev']").remove();
```

and append the new content to html head with

```
$('head').append(metaPagination);
```

with `var metaPagination = response.content.meta_pagination;`

Answer (score 1):

Kaminari will actually do this for you - see the relevant documentation here: https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari#the-rel_next_prev_link_tags-helper-method

If you want to delve a little deeper into the implementation, then it looks like this is the PR that added it: https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari/pull/200/files

TLDR - add this to your view

```
# In head:
<head>
  <%= yield :head %>
</head>

# Somewhere in body:
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= rel_next_prev_link_tags @articles %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, as it as well doesn't update the next/prev link(s) when a new page is loaded...

Comment: How are the links set up? Do they load in additional content via UJS, or client side JS that consumes a JSON feed from the server?

Comment: It's client side JS that consumes a JSON feed.

Comment: I updated the question and provided the method that renders the new page as JSON

Comment: So the issue here is that the whole page isn't refreshed when interacting with browsers - just the data. Thinking about this from an SEO perspective: as long as the pages are directly accessible too e.g if I visit http://www.bla.com/de/magazin?page=2 and it serves up an entire page - then search engines will pick up the right values, as the right tags will be rendered on page load